# Get innerHTML from component AFTER render

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to "steal" from the DOM the SVG code generated by an own component. I do it like this:

```html
<my-own-component id="my-component-id" #myComponentId
                        [data]="data"></my-own-component>
```

```js
onButtonClick() {
   this.data = someData;
   const svgCode = document.getElementById('my-component-id').innerHTML;
}
```

Also tried (also not working):

```js
@ViewChild('myComponentId') myComponentId;
...
onButtonClick() {
   this.data = someData;
   const svgCode = this.myComponentId.nativeElement.children[0].innerHTML;
}
```

The problem is that I get the content **before** Angular has applied the changes caused by `this.data = someData`, so the elements of the SVG are not included.
I have "solved" it introducing a 50ms timeout. This works, but is not a proper solution, is a bad patch:

```js
this.data = someData;        
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, null), 50));
const svgCode = document.getElementById('my-component-id').innerHTML;
```

I would like to be able to wait for Angular to finish rendering the component. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is AfterViewInit too soon for this as well ? maybe one of the ionic lifecycle hooks might work for you: https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle

Comment: What do you mean? `my-own-component.ngAfterViewInit` or `my-page.ngAfterViewInit`? I have tried `my-page`'s, no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elezan, the problem is that you need "give a breath to Angular". If you has, e.g.

```
<div>{{data}}</div>
click(){
  this.data="......."
  //here you don't can check the value of innerHtml
}
```

This "breath" is use a setTimeout

```
<div>{{data}}</div>
click(){
  this.data="......."
  setTimeout(()=>{
     //now here you can check the value of innerHtml
  })
}
```

Think that Angular, when you call to click function, execute all the instructions and "repaint" the app. So in the first case you're trying to get the innerHTML before Angular "repaint". Using a setTimeout you're saying to Angular: "Hey! you repaint and, after, don't forget the instructions into setTimeout" -see that setTimeout has no milliseconds-

Another way is inject in constructor [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) and use `markForCheck()` before try to get the innerHTML

**Update** Another example using observables

```
$observable.subscribe(res=>{
    this.data=res
    setTimeout(()=>{
         ..get the innerHTML
    })
})
```

Or promise

```
$promise.then(
  res=>{
    this.data=res
    setTimeout(()=>{
         ..get the innerHTML
    }),
  err=>{...}
)
```

Or `await`:

```js
const svgCode = await new Promise<string>(resolve => { 
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(document.getElementById('my-component-id').innerHTML));
    });  
});
```

Comment: Thanks Eliseo, I think this is what I was looking for. Now my problem is that what I do with `svgData` is returning it immediately (let's say my `onButtonClick` returns `Promise<string>`). How do I make `setTimeout` return what I need?

Comment: Is the same, you need use the setTimeout inside the "then" or if you're using observables inside the subscribe

Comment: Yes, this worked! I was using `await`s all over, so my code finally looks like this:
`const svgCode = await new Promise<string>(resolve => { setTimeout(() => { resolve(document.getElementById('my-component-id').innerHTML)); });  });`
Thanks a lot, @Eliseo

Answer (score 0):

Try AfterViewInit lifecycle hook. It's implementing like this

```
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // code that should be executed after view initialization
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a good idea. How do a wait for it from inside the father?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add **AfterViewInit** lifecycle hook with the class.  I would also suggest that you assign the property within the **OnInit** lifescycle as well. Your parent component should look like this

```
export class appComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{

 ngOnInit(): void {
  this.data = someData;
 }
 ngAfterViewInit(): void{
  const svgCode = document.getElementById('my-component-id').innerHTML;
 }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately is not that easy. `this.data = someData` happens when the user clicks a button, then is when `my-own-component` updates "too slow".  I will update the original question.

Comment: umm sorry, I missed that point. Then you can attach an output event in your child component. Once your child is getting rendered you can emit the output event and then catch it in your parent component and within that you can take the innerhtml.